# How to provide code coverage in exploratory manual testing (without unit tests)?

Tags: software-testing, code-coverage

1. I'd like to make code coverage with a help of some tool, which should write code coverage in a **runtime mode** (like Bullseye for C++ as my colleague tells me, but I don't know exactly and can't confirm it). I think it seems like Selenium IDE, but the result of testing shouldn't transform to junit for code coverage process, instead it should generate the visible report in a runtime mode or after testing.
2. The manual testing in this case is implied as **exploratory** testing or testing by strict following of check-lists.
3. We want such situation to do: we install some tool/plugin, make some manual tests in a runtime mode by testing some web-application, a tool/plugin simultaneously writes code coverage and finally generates a report. There should be no need to write additional commands or code for coverage process launch.
4. Before writing this question here I've red a lot of materials about **Sonar, Clover, Cobertura, Cassandra, Emma, JaCoCo, Visual Studio, dotCover, Хdebug** all over the net, including StackOverFlow. Unfortunately all of them didn't fit my task - they work only with unit tests or through the command line.
5. This task is not for solving a problem with our project. We are preparing some educational materials for testers and we put some info in there concerning tools for code coverage. These materials should be used both for automated as for manual testers, but predominantly for the last ones.

Does such a tool exist?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This will always need instrumentation and thus is technology specific. Your previous research confirms this: Bullseye for C++, dotCover for .NET etc. For testing a web application, the "tool" must run on the server side. You can't simply start "the tool" on the client, then run some tests and later get the coverage.

Comment: Why not, if he only wants coverage of the JavaScript? But, then again, he doesn't state what code he wantts to tets coverag eof, maybe it *is* all server side. @Mudassir, if you can give mor edetail then maybe we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Semantic Designs' (my company) [Test/Code Coverage Tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/) will collect code coverage data on an application regardless of whether it is exercised by a testing framework, by manual operation, simply during application execution, or during execution of the application as a server program if that is what it is.

They do so by instrumenting the source code; you compile and run the instrumented program.   A DumpTestCoverageVectors routine supplied by the tool is called by your application (either automatically from Main, from additional calls you add at convenient or interesting places, or from the testing framework on a per test/per test set basis as you see fit).  Dumped coverage data may used to build a coverage report, displayed superimposed on the source code in a GUI, or be accumulated or compared across runs or tests.  You can combine coverage data from different languages comprising an application, to get coverage data over the whole application.

Summary:

- Collects coverage data on running applications
- Generates report after application execution (and test coverage dump[s]).
- Usable to collect coverage on "exploratory execution"
- Available for Java, PHP, Visual Studio/GCC C and C++, C#, PL/SQL, other languages

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the trial version and could not find the documentation so helpful, also I could not find steps or tools to generate the probe installer. I was so much enthusiastic about going ahead with this tool but lack of support during evaluation forced me to look for other alternatives.

Comment: 1) The installer offered to show you the documentation. The documentation tells you everything you need to know.    2) You can find the documentation via the Start menu.  3) You can find a GUI to build a project and execute the instrumentation step via the Start menu. 4) The documentation tells you how to run the instrumenter in a script, if that's how you want to do it.  In addition, the download message tells you 2) and 3).  Lots of other people somehow manage.

Comment: There is no need to be defensive. Clearly this user does not believe so.

Comment: There are many users in the world that are incompetent, and believe it isn't them.  That doesn't make their declaration of a product or its support as poor correct.   Left standing by itself, it would produce an inappropriate view to the casual reader.    A defense in this case seemed necessary to make it clear where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [AQtime](https://smartbear.com/product/aqtime-pro/features/code-coverage-analysis/). Check if your project [is supported](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/43511/) before you buy the tool.

Answer (score 0):

The [Coco](https://www.froglogic.com/coco/) tool from froglogic (the company I work at) analyzes code coverage independent of whether the application is explored manually or whether it is driven through unit tests or an automation tool.

Coverage data will be provided latest on application exit. By sending a signal to the application dumps can be performed at any time while the application is still running, too.

By default coverage data is written out to the local file system but a custom i/o interface can be used to send the output over the network to a server.

The test explorations can all be named, assigned a status, free form HTML comments, compared and sorted.

The most important detail to clarify before choosing a coverage tool: which language (or languages) are being used? Only very few tools support more than one language.